# Optimizing SPARQL queries in MarkLogic

Tags: optimization, sparql, marklogic

In many SPARQL systems, you can optimize your queries by re-ordering the triples in a graph pattern.  In others, you cannot (the query engine optimizes them using some heuristics of its own)

In Jena, you can optimize queries by putting triple patterns that most restrict the result set early in the query (and making sure always to mention some variable that is already bound).  In other query engines, this strategy doesn't work (since they process the query differently)

Apparently, Marklogic SPARQL is sensitive to the ordering of the triple patterns (I have re-arranged some queries and found that they will go faster or slower, by as much as 10x).  But I can't find any rhyme or reason to which sequences go faster or slower.  The heuristics I have used successfully with Jena don't work with MarkLogic.

I have googled about and looked at the MarkLogic docs, and haven't found any advice about this.  Have any of the MarkLogic query engine writers made any notes about this?

Comment: "In many SPARQL systems, you can optimize your queries by re-ordering the triples in a graph pattern. "  This is actually kind of surprising, if true, since they're supposed to be equivalent.    Have you found any particular patterns (e.g., putting triples with fewer matches earlier produces faster results)?

Comment: The only requirement in SPARQL is that the results are the same regardless of order in the query.  Performance is an altogether different issue.

Comment: Most Apache Jena storage layers do some kind of partial reordering (depending on version); it's quite light though. If the partial reordering has two triple patterns of the same importance, it leaves them in the given order.

Comment: Scott is exactly right.  But just to answer Joshua's question, here's a simple example.  I'm running this over FIBO. 

This query is slow (takes several seconds):

SELECT * 
WHERE {
?s a owl:Class . 
?p a owl:ObjectProperty .
?p rdfs:domain ?s  . 
}

This query is fast (takes a blink of an eye):


SELECT * 
WHERE {
?s a owl:Class . 
?p rdfs:domain ?s  . 
?p a owl:ObjectProperty .
}


It never introduces a new variable (except at the start); that makes a huge difference (cross-product and filer vs. simple join)

Comment: I tried to typeset that last message, but it removed all of my newlines.  I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: So, Scott, do you have any advice?  The tricks I use in Jena (like the one from my comment) don't seem to work in ML, but the performance *does* seem to depend on order.  How do I determine a good order?

Comment: Have you done any profiling of the queries?  This could give you some information.  The "in memory triple index size" (database level) could make a difference if the issue is exceeding the current cache size.

Answer (score 2):

The optimization level gives a hint to the optimizer to tell it how much time to spend on finding the best query plan.
Any optimizer spends some time to find the best plan, but has to balance the time spent finding that plan against the goodness of using the best possible plan. Most of us have experienced this trade-off in real life (!)

Optimization level 1 says "do some work looking for the best plan, but don't go crazy". Level 2 says "do more work to find the best plan". Level 0 says "just take the query as it is".

For most queries level 1 is appropriate, and that's the default. If you have a particularly complex query, try it with level 2 and see if the extra time spent finding a plan to make the query faster actually pays off in overall query time. If you have very simple queries, try level 0.

Answer (score 0):

I asked our experts on the PM and Engineering teams inside MarkLogic. I was told, "you should get the same performance no matter what order you have for patterns, since we have a sophisticated query optimizer. If that's not true, please file a bug." It would also be useful to know what specific version of MarkLogic you are using, what [optimization level](http://docs.marklogic.com/sem:sparql#options), and some sample queries.

Comment: The docs do not say what the optimization levels do, just that "Levels of 0 (off), 1, and 2 are recognized. The default is 1."  What level should be used and what kinds of optimization can be expected?